# how to increase speed of tchart refresh()?

Tags: c#, performance, teechart

I have 16 graphs[maximum ] with 4 fastlines in each graph. In each graph 3 fastlines represent min , max and ideal value. 4th fastline is actual values from the hardware. I have to run the test for 18,000 samples. So , first 3 fastlines are already drawn and when the switch is on and data comes in , 4th fastline is drawn. In order to draw the 4th line, I use the method Series4.Add(actualvalue, "" , color.red) .
here is the problem. each time the sample is drawn on 4th line. chart has to be refreshed in order to view the plotting of that sample. that also redraws the other 3 fastlines with 18,000 samples in each . so it redraws that many samples without use again and again. I need to draw only 4th fastline.
I can  not use an array to fill the values up and then assign it as a source of fastline because I dont have any values beforehand. I tried series4.repaint() method and series4.refreshseries() method, but that doesnt repaint 4th series actually. we have to refresh the whole chart. 
 and therefore, it slows down the performance because of high number of samples in each fastline [18,000] and one graph with 4 fastlines and total 16 graphs like this.

I ve already done
Series4.AutoRepaint = false, Series4.DrawAllPoints = false;
Series4.XValues.Order = ValueListOrder.None , Series4.YValues.Order = ValueListOrder.None

Is there any way I can increase the performance ? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made a simple code, where I have added 4 charts with 4 FastLines with 18000 points for each fastline using a table to add a initialize values and after I update only the values of Series4. The performance is good for the number of values I am drawing:

```
        public Form1()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
         InitializeChart();
     }

    // Steema.TeeChart.Styles.FastLine Series1;

     Timer timer1, timer2,timer3, timer4;
     Random r;
     DateTime dt;
   DateTime[] Xvalues1;
   double[] Yvalues1; 
     Steema.TeeChart.TChart tChart1, tChart2, tChart3,tChart4;
     private void InitializeChart()
     {

         tChart1 = new TChart();
         tChart2 = new TChart();
         tChart3 = new TChart();
         tChart4 = new TChart();
         this.Controls.Add(tChart1);
         this.Controls.Add(tChart2);
         this.Controls.Add(tChart3);
         this.Controls.Add(tChart4);

         //Initialize Locations and size

         this.Width = 908;
         this.Height = 600;

         //Location
         tChart1.Left = 12;
         tChart1.Top = 53;
         tChart2.Left = 468;
         tChart2.Top = 53;
         tChart3.Left = 12;
         tChart3.Top = 318;
         tChart4.Left = 468;
         tChart4.Top = 318;

         //Size
         tChart1.Width = 373;
         tChart1.Height = 236;
         tChart2.Width = 373;
         tChart2.Height = 236;
         tChart3.Width = 373; 
         tChart3.Height = 236;
         tChart4.Width = 373;
         tChart4.Height = 236;      

         tChart1.Aspect.View3D = false;
         tChart2.Aspect.View3D = false;
         tChart3.Aspect.View3D = false;
         tChart4.Aspect.View3D = false;

         tChart1.Legend.Visible = false;
         tChart2.Legend.Visible = false;
         tChart3.Legend.Visible = false;
         tChart4.Legend.Visible = false;


         tChart1.Panel.Gradient.Visible = false;
         tChart2.Panel.Gradient.Visible = false;
         tChart3.Panel.Gradient.Visible = false;
         tChart4.Panel.Gradient.Visible = false;


         tChart1.Axes.Bottom.AxisPen.Visible = false;
         tChart2.Axes.Bottom.AxisPen.Visible = false;
         tChart3.Axes.Bottom.AxisPen.Visible = false;
         tChart4.Axes.Bottom.AxisPen.Visible = false;

         tChart1.Axes.Left.AxisPen.Visible = false;
         tChart2.Axes.Left.AxisPen.Visible = false;
         tChart3.Axes.Left.AxisPen.Visible = false;
         tChart4.Axes.Left.AxisPen.Visible = false;

         //Series
         tChart1.AutoRepaint = false;
         tChart2.AutoRepaint = false;
         tChart3.AutoRepaint = false;
         tChart4.AutoRepaint = false;

         for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
         {
             new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.FastLine(tChart1.Chart);
             new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.FastLine(tChart2.Chart);
             new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.FastLine(tChart3.Chart);
             new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.FastLine(tChart4.Chart);

             tChart1[i].XValues.DateTime=true;
             tChart2[i].XValues.DateTime = true;
             tChart3[i].XValues.DateTime = true;
             tChart4[i].XValues.DateTime = true;
             InitialDataSeries(tChart1[i]);
             InitialDataSeries(tChart2[i]);
             InitialDataSeries(tChart3[i]);
             InitialDataSeries(tChart4[i]);

         }

         //Axes labels
         tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Labels.DateTimeFormat = "dd/MM";
         tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Labels.Angle = 90;
         tChart2.Axes.Bottom.Labels.DateTimeFormat = "dd/MM";
         tChart2.Axes.Bottom.Labels.Angle = 90;
         tChart3.Axes.Bottom.Labels.DateTimeFormat = "dd/MM";
         tChart3.Axes.Bottom.Labels.Angle = 90;
         tChart4.Axes.Bottom.Labels.DateTimeFormat = "dd/MM";
         tChart4.Axes.Bottom.Labels.Angle = 90;
         tChart1.AutoRepaint = true;
         tChart2.AutoRepaint = true;
         tChart3.AutoRepaint = true;
         tChart4.AutoRepaint = true;
         tChart1.Refresh();
         tChart2.Refresh();
         tChart3.Refresh();
         tChart4.Refresh();

         //Timer
         timer1 = new Timer();
         timer1.Start();
         timer1.Interval = 100;
         timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);

     }

     void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         //See the chart data updated.
         tChart1[0].Visible = false;
         tChart1[1].Visible = false;
         tChart1[2].Visible = false;
         PopulateSeries(tChart1[3]);
         PopulateSeries(tChart2[3]);
         PopulateSeries(tChart3[3]);
         PopulateSeries(tChart4[3]);

     }
     private void PopulateSeries(Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Series Series1)
     {
         r = new Random();
         dt = DateTime.Now;
         tChart1.AutoRepaint = false;
         tChart2.AutoRepaint = false;
         tChart3.AutoRepaint = false;
         tChart4.AutoRepaint = false; 
         // show only 50 points - delete the rest
         while (Series1.Count > 10000)
         {
             Series1.Delete(0);

         }
         if (Series1.Count > 10000)
         {
            Series1.Delete(0);

         }
         else
         {
             for (int t = 0; t < 100; t++)
             {

                 Series1.Add(dt, r.Next(1000));
                 dt = dt.AddSeconds(15);
             }
         }
         tChart1.AutoRepaint = true;
         tChart2.AutoRepaint = true;
         tChart3.AutoRepaint = true;
         tChart4.AutoRepaint = true;
         tChart1.Refresh();
         tChart2.Refresh();
         tChart3.Refresh();
         tChart4.Refresh();
     }

     private void InitialDataSeries(Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Series Series1)
     {    
         //Arrays
         dt = DateTime.Now;
         r = new Random();
         Xvalues1 = new DateTime[18000];
         Yvalues1 = new double[18000];
         (Series1 as Steema.TeeChart.Styles.FastLine).DrawAllPoints = false;
         for (int j = 0; j < 18000; j++)
         {
             Xvalues1[j] = dt;
             dt = dt.AddSeconds(15);
             Yvalues1[j] = r.Next(1000);
         }

         Series1.Add(Xvalues1, Yvalues1);
     }
```

Could you tell us if it help you? On the other hand, if my code doesn't help you I recommend you use TeeChartDirect2D,  this is ideal for the high speed data throughput required by DSP realtime applications. See the White paper, [Boosting graphics-rendering performance in Windows Forms](http://www.teechart.net/files/teechartnet/WhitePaper_Direct2D.pdf), for a closer look.

Thanks,

Comment: Thank you but I can not make other 3 lines invisible. I would want to see position of the 4th line in real time with min max and ideal limits. so after making them invisible, it draws at an excellent speed. but i can not hide other 3 lines. so, I can not do fastline.visible= false and fastline.active= false. surprisingly active also hides the fastline. so seems like active and visible serve the same purpose. is there a way i can use fastline.draw() , fastline.repaint(), fastline.refreshseries() to update only 4th line ?

Comment: I also tried to download direct2d demo. graphicscontrol.dll is missing for winforms app. searched the zip file , but there is no dll file like that.also it says Matrix3x2 does not exist.

Comment: also   private void PopulateSeries(Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Series Series1) and  private void InitialDataSeries(Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Series Series1) . shouldnt it be Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Fastline instead of Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Series

Comment: i did this in order to implement direct2d. no improvements.am I missing anything? Chart1.Graphics3D = new Graphics3DDirect2D(Chart1.Chart);            Chart1.Aspect.TextRenderingHint =TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixel;            Chart1.Aspect.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighSpeed;            Chart1.Graphics3D.BufferStyle = BufferStyle.None;            Chart1.Graphics3D.SupportsID=false;            Chart1.Graphics3D.Supports3DText=false;            Chart1.Graphics3D.TextRenderingHint= TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixel;            Chart1.Graphics3D.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighSpeed;

Comment: Hello saumil,
First, you need know that TeeChartDirec2D is included in the installer of TeeChartFor.Net. You can download in the costumer page http://www.steema.com/download/net. In it there is samples, help you see as you must use TeeChartDirec2D in the correct way. If you find  problems with it or you can not achive improve your performance, please send me your project, because I can try to help you. Thanks,

Comment: Hi Sandra, here is the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k8mbd4hcqd2vp6u/Pro.zip) . Please go through the read me file first. Let me know if you get any problem in running the project.you will have to add teechart and slimdx references in the project. Thanks !

Comment: I have made a project in the way that chart is a child window. so you can do all the modifications in childwin.cs and its designer. main file gets the data from demo file and save it into array and includes timer.

Comment: for the large number of samples, if you make other 3 series visible= false, active = false, then performance will improve and transition will be smooth. but certainly I want smoother transition without hiding other series.

Comment: Hello saumil, 
I have answered you in this link: http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=13938&p=61250#p61250 please, see it. Thanks.